# Passing dynamic value in Oval annotation

Tags: java, validation, oval

If you are having a class

```
public class object {
   @NotNull
   @NotEmpty
   @Length(max=32)
   private String name;
}
```

If this bean is validated thru Oval validation framework, How to pass the value 32 dynamically? The reason why i raise this question is i am having the value 32 in the xml file which needs to be passed over here. I also know Oval has it own xml configuration framework. But i don't want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Annotation values must be static, so you can't put a dynamic value in '@Length'.

But you can write custom validations with the `@ValidateWithMethod` or `@CheckWith` annotation. In this validation method/class you can pull your value from XML and validate it against your field `name`. You can find some simple examples here:
http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#complex-class-specific-constraints